# Loading a PLIST from web server

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, plist, reachability

Trying to have the ability to load a plist from a URL and have it overwrite the current plist that is there.  The code below works on the simulator but when checking on an iPhone 4 device it doesn't pull down the updated content?  Any words of wisdom for an new guy to Xcode?

```
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];

if ((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)){

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SpecialCases.plist"];
    NSURL *theFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.awebsite.com"];
    NSDictionary *replace = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theFileURL];
    if (replace != nil){
    [replace writeToFile:finalPath
                 atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't pull down the updated content", what exactly do you mean? Set a breakpoint and step through the code - does it go into your conditional branch? Check the values of the variables. Is replace nil, any errors thrown?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to check reachability status in this situation. Just go ahead and download the plist _in background_. If downloading fails, you will know. Did you try commenting out the `if`?

Comment: Yeah i didn't think about throwing that if statement in there until later.  I've already take the reachability thing out.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot write to your application's bundle on an iOS device, as that isn't part of the sandbox you are allowed to edit. You must save your file to the documents directory, like this:

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SpecialCases.plist"];
```

And then later load the plist from there, not your app bundle.